# openstack instance's image name lost after integration with ceph rbd

Tags: openstack, ceph

after integrated with ceph rbd,my openstack could not show "image name" of my instance, is there any option that controlling this feature?

```
grep "^[^#]" /etc/glance/glance-api.conf
[DEFAULT]
show_image_direct_url = true
[cors]
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://glance:GLANCE_DBPASS@controller/glance
[glance_store]
stores = rbd
default_store = rbd
rbd_store_pool = images
rbd_store_ceph_conf = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
rbd_store_chunk_size = 8
[image_format]
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:35357
memcached_servers = controller:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = glance
password = GLANCE_PASS
[matchmaker_redis]
[oslo_concurrency]
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_messaging_zmq]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[paste_deploy]
flavor = keystone
[profiler]
[store_type_location_strategy]
[task]
[taskflow_executor]
```

```
[root@controller ~]# grep "^[^#]" /etc/nova/nova.conf
[DEFAULT]
enabled_apis = osapi_compute,metadata
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:RABBIT_PASS@controller
my_ip = 172.18.3.100
use_neutron = True
firewall_driver = nova.virt.firewall.NoopFirewallDriver
debug = true
[api]
auth_strategy = keystone
[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller/nova_api
[barbican]
[cache]
[cells]
[cinder]
os_region_name = RegionOne
[compute]
[conductor]
[console]
[consoleauth]
[cors]
[crypto]
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller/nova
[devices]
[ephemeral_storage_encryption]
[filter_scheduler]
[glance]
api_servers = http://controller:9292
[guestfs]
[healthcheck]
[hyperv]
[ironic]
[key_manager]
[keystone]
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_url = http://controller:5000/v3
memcached_servers = controller:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = nova
password = NOVA_PASS
[libvirt]
[matchmaker_redis]
[metrics]
[mks]
[neutron]
url = http://controller:9696
auth_url = http://controller:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
region_name = RegionOne
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = NEUTRON_PASS
service_metadata_proxy = true
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = METADATA_SECRET
[notifications]
[osapi_v21]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/nova/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_messaging_zmq]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[pci]
[placement]
os_region_name = RegionOne
project_domain_name = default
project_name = service
auth_type = password
user_domain_name = default
auth_url = http://controller:5000/v3
username = placement
password = PLACEMENT_PASS
[quota]
[rdp]
[remote_debug]
[scheduler]
[serial_console]
[service_user]
[spice]
[upgrade_levels]
[vault]
[vendordata_dynamic_auth]
[vmware]
[vnc]
enabled = true
vncserver_listen = $my_ip
vncserver_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
[workarounds]
[wsgi]
[xenserver]
[xvp]
```

```
[root@controller ~]# grep "^[^#]" /etc/cinder/cinder.conf
[DEFAULT]
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:RABBIT_PASS@controller
auth_strategy = keystone
my_ip = 172.17.3.100
enabled_backends = ceph
glance_api_version = 2
[backend]
[backend_defaults]
[barbican]
[brcd_fabric_example]
[cisco_fabric_example]
[coordination]
[cors]
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://cinder:CINDER_DBPASS@controller/cinder
[fc-zone-manager]
[healthcheck]
[key_manager]
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:5000
memcached_servers = controller:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = cinder
password = CINDER_PASS
[matchmaker_redis]
[nova]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/cinder/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_messaging_zmq]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[oslo_reports]
[oslo_versionedobjects]
[profiler]
[service_user]
[ssl]
[vault]
[ceph]
volume_driver = cinder.volume.drivers.rbd.RBDDriver
volume_backend_name = ceph
rbd_pool = volumes
rbd_ceph_conf = /etc/ceph/ceph.conf
rbd_flatten_volume_from_snapshot = false
rbd_max_clone_depth = 5
rbd_store_chunk_size = 4
rados_connect_timeout = -1
```

[[image: ]]
[[image: ]]
[[image: ]]

Comment: I think this might be due to the image's visibilty? Can you check it? I think the image name will only appear as long as the image is public. Any other state will end up with a blank field in horizon

Comment: I made images all public..